# Objective-C, .m / .mm performance difference?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c++

I tend to use the .mm extension by default when creating new classes so that I can use ObjC++ later on if I require it.

Is there any disadvantage to doing this? When would you prefer `.m`?  Does `.m` compile to a faster executable (since C is generally faster than C++)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Before Xcode 4.0 (released in 2011), which can use the [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) frontend tool chain for both, the major disadvantage to using `.mm` over `.m` for "normal" Objective-C was that compile times are significantly higher for Objective-C++. This is because the C++ compiler takes longer than the C compiler.

A better strategy is to use `.m` by default. If you need to use Objective-C++ later in development, there is no harm in renaming the file to use a `.mm` extension. If you so from within Xcode, the project will be automatically updated to use the newly named file.

Of course all of the standard caveats apply once you try to compare Objective-C++ vs. Objective-C performance at run time. Since Objective-C++ is a C++ superset while Objective-C is a C superset, you are dealing with two different languages each with performance tradeoffs at runtime. Given that you're using Objective-X at all, you are likely writing a user-level application (not a systems level app) and the difference in performance between C and C++ wil likely be completely determined by your abilities to code efficient algorithms in each language. If you're a C++ developer, you'll likely code better than in C and visa versa. So, as always, use the appropriate tool for the job.

For reference, you may also be interested in this answer: [C vs C++ (Objective-C vs Objective-C++) for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735085/c-vs-c-objective-c-vs-objective-c-for-iphone/1735666#1735666)

**UPDATE Feb 17, 2012** As of Xcode 4.0 (with LLVM 3.0), Clang has supported Objective-C++. Even C++11 support is quite strong now.

Answer (score 9):

If you only use C features, .mm files should generate code that performs very similar to .m

There is also no downside to renaming a file from .m to .mm later when you desire C++ features

Comment: so the .m extension is essentially deprecated for iPhone / Obj-C++ development?

Comment: also, why wouldn't GCC just assume Obj-C++ at all times provided the architecture is supported?  What is gained by disqualifying C++ code from certain files?

Comment: The .m extension is not deprecated, in fact it's the default.  Assuming ObjC++ is a bad idea because there are some cases where C++ is different from C (symbol mangling is the most visible, but there are many others). Allowing C++ in .c files would be just as wrong--they're two different languages.

Comment: Objective-C is used for it's compatibility with C. `.m` is the default extension for Obj-C files. As mentioned, there are some differences in how these things are compiled. For example, C-structs are implemented as classes whose data members have public visibility by default, vs. their original implementation in C.