# C Language: what does the .mm extension stand for?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

A project with some Objective-C has a few C classes with the implementation files having a **.mm** extension.

```
file.h
file.mm
```

What does the **.mm** mean? Shouldn't it just be **.m**?

Comment: http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The extension `.mm` is the extension for the `C++` compilation unit expected by the Objective-C compiler, while the `.m` extension is the extension for the `C` compilation unit expected by the Objective-C compiler.

That's assuming you don't use a compiler flag to override the file extension, [as this gentleman has done](http://sseyod.blogspot.com/2009/02/objective-c.html).

Answer (score 29):

Objective C++, mixes C++ and Objective C.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B

Answer (score 20):

.mm files are like .cpp files to the Objective-C compiler. They activate the C++ compiler instead of the C compiler.

The following question on performance has additional useful information:

[Objective-C, .m / .mm performance difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317868/objective-c-m-mm-performance-difference)