# What language is Brackets-shell written in and how it works

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

I have just come across an application called brackets, which is written in javascript/html/css and it runs in something called ["brackets-shell"](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell), bracket-shell is based on something called "CEF3". I took a look at its source code. It is mainly c++ but had a file with .mm extension.

My questions are:

What are CEF3 and .mm file extension?

What is brackets-shell written in (what compiler will compile it)?

Is it some kind of "browser", so it just opens html/css/javascript?

Comment: There's a link to the wiki right there in the readme.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something with adequate documentation via a site linked to from the question itself.

Comment: @Pointy It's only about "How to build brackets-shell" which could answer one of my questions (what compiler will compile it?) but still it doesn't

Comment: It's a **wiki** - there's more than one page there.

Comment: @DaveNewton Whatever, write an answer(just link), so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [CEF3: Chromium Embedded Browser](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)
- [*.mm are Objective-C files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335285/c-language-what-does-the-mm-extension-stand-for)
- [brackets-shell is a Node (e.g., JS) app](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-brackets-shell)