# xcode5 can not recognize c++ code

Tags: c++, xcode5

I have modify MapCtrl.m to MapCtrl.mm,but xocde5 can not recognize the c++ code,
    //MapCtrl.mm

```
BMKMapPoint* points = new BMKMapPoint[planPointCounts];

delete []points;
```

The error is:

```
/Users/jinxudong/Documents/在线生成平台/WeiPai/ViewCtrl/MapCtrl.mm:365:35: Use of undeclared identifier 'new'
/Users/jinxudong/Documents/在线生成平台/WeiPai/ViewCtrl/MapCtrl.mm:327:3: Use of undeclared    identifier 'delete'; did you mean 'undelete'?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335285/c-language-what-does-the-mm-extension-stand-for or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652186/why-do-objective-c-files-use-the-m-extension

Comment: i know .mm is for c++ compile ,my questions is why comes out the error

Comment: Maybe try renaming your file into a recognizable file format(?) such as `.cpp`