# Using UIKit from C/C++

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, uikit

The questions might have been already asked, but I want to understand if iPhone's frameworks limited only to Objective-C use or it could also be accessed from C/C++ code?

For example, is it possible to use standard iPhone controls from C/C++ code? Are standard classes like NSArray, NSSet accessible from C/C++ code?

If they are, could any one give a link to some examples how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use C++ with Cocoa Instead of Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525609/use-c-with-cocoa-instead-of-objective-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mix Objective C with C++. Just rename your source file to `.mm`.

Some Foundation classes such as NSArray and NSSet are toll-free bridges to CoreFoundation objects like CFArray and CFSet. The latter is a pure C library that you can use without ObjC.

---

UIKit is a pure Objective-C framework. You *could* use UIKit with C and C++ as the Objective-C runtime is accessible from pure C functions such as `objc_msgSend`, e.g.

```
id UIView = objc_getClass("UIView");
SEL alloc = sel_registerName("alloc");
id view = objc_msgSend(UIView, alloc);
// ...
```

but it is not reliable, e.g.

```
objc_msgSend(view, sel_registerName("setAlpha:"), 0.4);
```

will **not** do what you want.

You could isolate the UI part and write ObjC just for that part. Create a C interface between the UI and the backend, which you may use C++ or any (allowed) languages.

Comment: He can actually write C++ classes in such a way that they are compatible with Objective-C classes, but keyword messages are still a problem.

Comment: Why won't `objc_msgSend(view, sel_registerName("setAlpha:"), 0.4);` do what he wants?