# C++ and Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c

I need to use C++ file in my project, it's called `CAXException.hpp`, and row in project targets "Compile Sources As" - "According to file type" not Objective-C++. But when it's compiling it always displays me error `error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CAXException'`
in code:

```
class CAXException //<-------error here

{}
```

Please help me to fix it..

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525609/use-c-with-cocoa-instead-of-objective-c/529017#529017) has a lot of information about what you need to do to use C++ with Objective C. And the other answers on that same page should pretty helpful too - regardless of the flame war in the comments.

Comment: Which one is it, objective C or C++?

Comment: If you're following convention, an .hpp file is included as a header file in an other translation unit. Please edit your question to tell us a bit more about *that* file: is it C, C++, Objective-C, or Objective-C++? How are you including the .hpp file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a C++ header file (`.hpp`) that you want to include from Objective-C file. Unfortunately, you can't do that directly. You'll have to use a workaround.

The easiest is to change the compilation option of each and every Objective-C file (`.m`) that include this C++ header file (either directly or indirectly) to be compiled as an Objective-C++ file. This can be done either by renaming the files to `.mm` extension or by changing the option for the compiler for the file.

If this work for you, this will be the easiest, however Objective-C++ is not a complete superset of Objective-C (as C++ is not a superset of C), and some valid Objective-C is invalid Objective-C++ (if C++ keywords are used as variables names).

If this happens, you'll have to create an Objective-C wrapper to the class, with an implementation in Objective-C++ that simply delegate to the C++ class. That is create an `CAXExceptionWrapper.h` Objective-C file, containing something like:

```
@interface CAXExceptionWrapper {
  @private
    void* _CAXExceptionImpl;
}
- (id)init;
// ...
@end
```

And an `CAXExceptionWrapper.mm' Objective-C++ file containing:

```
@import "CAXException.hpp"
@implementation CAXExceptionWrapper
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _CAXException = new CAXExceptionWrapper;
    }
    return self;
}
// ...
@end
```

And then in your Objective-C files, include the wrapper Objective-C header instead of the C++ header.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CAXException //<-------error here
{};
 ^^^
```

you are missing the `;`

And Your compiler seems not to recognize the C++ keyword `class`, which is strange. Most likely, you are missing some `;` before this class definition or some other syntax error but before this.

Comment: @mazder the error is before that line. Most likely you are also missing a `;` at the end of a class declared above that one.

Comment: When I set in project targets "Compile Sources As" - "Objective C++" this file compiles normal, just about 100 other errors in other files (facebook connect and twitter libraries)

Comment: Just fixed this problem, `#import` from header file (.h) can't be declared it's must be in the `.mm` file.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that that header is being included from an objective-c (.m extension) source code file. The source code file that includes that header must be an objective c++ one, i.e. ends with .mm or you can force objective c++ by explicitly changing the "Compile sources as..." setting.