# including c++ libraries in ios programming

Tags: c++, ios, bigint

I'm developing an ios app that's very basic and uses objective almost all of the time. However my app needs to deal with big integer numbers (eg: 2^200) and add and multiply them. To achieve that I need to include a c++ library called bigint that allows these operations on huge integers. The problem I have is that when I include the bigint project I get many errors and I thought that this could be because it's c++ and can't mix with objective c. I'm new to this idea and was wondering if there are any steps i need to take to correctly add a c++ library to an objective c project. By the way I'm not using opengl or anything complicated just simple ui and some quartz stuff.

Update:
I did everything you guys said, I changed all the extensions to .mm and added the bigint library. My project ran perfectly without errors before doing these things. I get an error when i do this and I get an error even if I don't even add the library. just changing the file extensions to .mm gives me the following error.
[image]

This just doesnt make sense since everything ran fine before and I don't have any duplicates in my program. I have no idea why just changing the extensions to .mm could cause this error. Any ideas guys?

Comment: You have to include more information than just 'I get many errors', because it is hard to prophesy what may be going wrong in your program. But for reference, I am able to include the bigint libraries in Xcode project by dragging its folder into the project as a reference. This after renaming all the implementation and header files as brainjam described in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mix in C++ files, but use a .cpp suffix for them (and .hpp for their corresponding header files).  If you want to mix C++ and Obj-C in the same file, you can do that, but give it a .mm suffix.

Comment: I've done those things but i still get the errors, I think I need to do something more complex than that.maybe something to do with the project or target setting.

Comment: @Milad. Using C++ with Obj-C is pretty common, and there are lots of more detailed questions/answers on this subject here - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525609/use-c-with-cocoa-instead-of-objective-c.  You should be more specific about the error messages you're getting, and what you've done (provide the details by editing your original question, not by stuffing them into comments.)