# Is it possible to write the core of an application in C++ and use Obj-C and Cocoa for UI?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

If so how should the C++ code be prepared so it's easily consumed in Obj-C code?

Also is this a valid way of creating cross platform applications if you choose not to use GTK or Qt?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525609/use-c-with-cocoa-instead-of-objective-c) is a very good answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we have shipping applications built this way. We have an OS layer (Obj-C on Mac, a Combination of C++, C++/CLI and C# combination on Windows) and a shared portable layer.

One primary concern is to be disciplined in the class definitions so that OS particulars (Obj-C or C++/CLI syntax for example) does not get used in the portable/shared code.

You could create libraries to isolate code but we haven't needed to do that.

Comment: I know in Windows you can use C++ code through DLLs but how do you import the C++ layer into your objective-c code?

Comment: We have an XCode project which simply includes both sets of files. We organize by folders but it's all included in the output application. We have static libraries for a few sets of C++ files which are simply linked into the main project as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's definitely possible. It's not even all that uncommon. For example, most of WebKit is C++ code. You can use Objective-C++ to bridge between C++ and Objective-C code.

Comment: can the C++ code be made into a library in the way that dlls work on Windows and have the library imported into an xcode project?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible and really useful. Sometimes it would better to split you application into 2 parts: Objective-C GUI application and C/C++ daemon with business logic. It simplifies cross-platform application development process.

Comment: Can the two be started and stopped together or the daemon must continuously run in the background?

Comment: You could use launchctl for managing your daemon activities, like start-up, restarting, termination, etc.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/launchctl.1.html
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html