# C++ Mac libraries

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm using OS X Lion, using C++.  I've set the dialect to C++11, and the standard library to libc++.  In Visual C++, I've heard about the windows.h library and the operations that can be performed with it (such as popping up windows), and was wondering if there were any similar libraries for Mac, and where I can learn about them.  I have searched quite a bit, but to no avail.

Comment: This is not really an option. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525609/use-c-with-cocoa-instead-of-objective-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking either at [Carbon](https://developer.apple.com/carbon/) (which is now obsolete) or [Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html), which is a modern Objective-C API. You're best off using a combination of C++ and Objective-C to make a graphical app for OS X so you can use the Cocoa library.

Take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525609/use-c-with-cocoa-instead-of-objective-c) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cocoa Objective-C api or you can use cross-platform c++ solutions, such as `Qt` or `wxWidgets`