# Adding NSTimer to a C++ class

Tags: c++, objective-c, nstimer

I have a c++ class in my objective-c application (TC.h and TC.mm) and it has two methods as follows.

```
//TC.h
class TC 
{
public:
  void SetupPollTimer();
  void Timeout();
}

//TC.mm
void TC::Timeout() 
{
    //Inside timer handler

}
void TC::SetupPollTimer() 
{
    //Setup Timer
    //Want to use NSTimer here..

}
```

Basically when I call SetupPollTimer(), I want to start a NSTimer, with NSInvocation so that it repeatedly calls Timeout method. 
First off all, is this even possible. If so, I would really appreciate any thoughts or guidance regarding the same.

Comment: Yes. Sorry..edited the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you would just use the CoreFoundation equivalent; CFRunLoopTimer.

Using an NSTimer instead would often mean you need a binding objc object type to use as the parameter for your timer callbacks.

Doing that, you would set TC's `this` to the timer callback's context info. Then you would be able to access your TC instance in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post:

[Use C++ with Cocoa Instead of Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525609/use-c-with-cocoa-instead-of-objective-c)

Apparently, you can't write Cocoa-Applications entirely in C++, but there are ways to share code between C++ and Objective C.

**EDIT**

Ok, another option would be to add the timer to the class that handles that CPP file and fire the CPP method whenever the NSTimer fires in the handler-file.

I found a few techniques to use C++ instances in Objective C, but not the other way around.

Comment: This is a Cocoa app i.e. with appdelegates, objective-c interfaces/implementations etc. One of the classes HAS to be in C++. This CPP class needs to have a NSTimer running and call its own method...similar to the question I have posted. Basically, I am guessing you can pass the function pointer of the c++ method to NSInvocation, thus making it the selector, but not getting any concrete examples to use..