# How to create a static library in objective C and use it in pure c++ project?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to create a static library in objective C by using cocoa framework and use it in pure c++ project.Is it possible?

Comment: Your library would presumably need to have a pure "C" API, even if it's Objective-C under the hood.

Comment: Or a C++ API, using Objective-C++.

Comment: did my answer help you ? if so please upvote / mark as top answer. if not please add comments or more details so other users looking for the same will know what to do

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible due to the massive differences in how cocoa uses late binding versus c++ compile-time bound.

This question has more or less been answered here:

[Use C++ with Cocoa Instead of Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525609/use-c-with-cocoa-instead-of-objective-c)